# To provide multiple actions for a form with 2 submit buttons in CodeIgniter1

Tags: codeigniter

I have a form with 2 submit buttons , I need to give 2 actions for the form based on the submit button I click,How can this be achieved in codeigniter,Thanks Friends.  Here is the sample code.

```
<?php
    $attributes = array('name' => 'frmdisplay');

    echo form_open('display/goto1', $attributes);
?>

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Showone" name="goto1btn" />

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Showtwo" name="goto2btn" />
```

Here how can i provide action to both the pages  display/goto1 and display/goto2 based on submit btn pressed. THat means if first submit button is pressed thwn action should be display/goto1 and for second submit button action should be display/goto2.

Comment: should javascript be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, isn't the `name` of the submit button passed as a key in the `post` data? If so, you can just check that:

```
if (!empty($this->input->post("goto1btn")))
{
     // goto1btn pressed
}
else if (!empty($this->input->post("goto2btn")))
{
     // goto2btn pressed
}
else
{
     // no button pressed
}
```